# Dropbox.py on RHEL 6

Tags: python, dropbox, rhel-6

I'm trying to run a headless install of Dropbox on RHEL 6. The daemon seems to be running, but when I try to use Dropbox's associated dropbox.py tool to control the daemon, it fails to run with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dropbox.py", line 26, in <module>
    import locale
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/locale.py", line 202, in <module>
    import re, operator
ImportError: /home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/operator.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS2_AsDefaultEncodedString
```

I'm running the current RHEL build of Python 2.6:

```
root@cedar [/home/dropbox/.dropbox-dist]# rpm -qv python
python-2.6.6-29.el6_3.3.x86_64
```

(I'm not sure if this would be better suited to Stack Overflow since it is on the verge of being a programming issue, but since I'm trying to use a program straight from Dropbox, I placed it here.)

Answer (score 2):

I had placed `dropbox.py` in the .dropbox-dist folder. When I moved it out of that folder, it seems Python no longer ran into a conflict with `operator.so`. So far as I can tell, this resolved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me, once I moved it out, the script worked. Just moved it up one level and voila. Nice one.